# running multiple website through one site on apache2

Tags: php, web-development, python, django, administration

I am new to web development but giving it a try to learn and whilst make use of it

I have installed sites [gogs](https://gogs.io) , pydio and reviewboard on apache2 running on Raspbian.

right now I have to start each site separately, to start gogs which uses same localhost but different port (3000) and pydio is using 80.

I have enabled the site pydio which is located in `/var/www/php/`

i make the pydio site live by `sudo a2ensite` which creates symlink from sites available to sites-enabled.

now i want to put the gogs which is based on [go lang](https://golang.org) and [reviewboard](https://www.reviewboard.org) which is based on python/Django platform under

```
/var/www/----|
             |
             go--gogs
             |
          python-reviewboard
             |
            php---pydio
```

and all these sites to be enabled when running just single site (home.conf under sites available) How to achieve this ?

Comment: For clarification, are you saying you want all of these to run as folders under one domain such as example.com/go--gogs, example.com/python-reviewboard, and example.com/php---pydio or something similar?

Comment: Yes, I very much meant that (y)

Comment: I am not familiar enough with these products to answer, however, it does appear that go gogs is it's own binary. Is there a way you know of to run it under Apache? I assume the others use PHP and Python as per your labels.

Comment: I don't know golang either but I think it's launching `gogs`. Binary like how python launch temporary webpages using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer  `  on port 8000

Comment: I do not believe you can have these available through Apache other than to proxy from Apache to the other applications. You may want to look into how to reverse proxy other sites/applications using Apache. I am going through something like this with an Tomcat application. It is possible, just not sure how yet. Cheers!!

Comment: When you say reverse proxy other sites/applications you mean I should check reverse proxy of `gogs` ?

Comment: No. Apache allows you to tie paths such as /gog to another site somewhere either on the local server or another, even on another port, as long as the application is web based. The Apache .htaccess directive is ProxyPass. However, that is a whole world unto itself. I am used to hardware proxy routers and only once use Apache as a proxy to collect hacker data and that was a very long time ago. The whole Apache proxy thing has changed and I am still figuring it out. In fact, I have not used a proxy in about a decade now. Time flies!

Comment: PS: using mmap I have found it is using ppp service  
`3000/tcp open  ppp`